# Using require and include from PHP class to load outside the class

Tags: php

I've been attempting to create a PHP loader class that'll take care of all of my directory issues. I've mostly gotten it to work, but it breaks when including global functions.

Here's what I'm using:

```
<?php
class Loader {
    public function __construct() { ... }
    private function check_if_file_exists($file) { ... }
    public function load($file) {
        $this->check_if_file_exists($file); //Throws fatal Exception if not a file
        //The "important" stuff: works with global vars, not with global functions:
        extract($GLOBALS, EXTR_REFS);
        ob_start();
        require_once "{$this->path}/$file";
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

This lets me do the following:

```
<?php
$loader = new Loader();
$loader->load('file.php'); //Class takes care of path stuff--don't worry about it
//This works:
print $variable_in_file_dot_php;

//This does NOT work:
function_in_file_dot_php();
```

How can I make it so that `function_in_file_dot_php();` works?

Comment: I am aware of autoloading in PHP. That is not what I am referring to. I am referring to using `include` in *non* class files.

Comment: $variable_in_file_dot_php only works if it's already defined in $GLOBALS... which makes it rather pointless, since you must know what's in your code before you load it...  function_in_file() should work, can i see your file.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Better you use AutoLoader class already available in php.Refer this url http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

i'm going to try to answer your question as a *technical curiousity*, but i strongly advise you not to do this.

Referring to the include/require [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) I see that variables defined inside included files will inherit the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of the line that called require.  In your case this will be the variable scope of Loader::load() method inside some instance of Loader class

Therefore **$variable_in_file** will not be available globally.  unless you

1. define the $var before calling the include statement, thus giving it global scope.
2. declare it global inside your calling method (Loader::load())

You acomplish #2 with extract($GLOBALS...) however in order to do #1, you must have a priori knowledge of what is being included before you include it... invalidating your attempt at generalization with the Loader class.

**function_in_file()** however should be available in the global scope, I'd like to see your file.php and error message.  Here's mine.

$cat foo.php

```
    public function load($file) {
        extract($GLOBALS,EXTR_REFS);
        require_once $file;
    }
}

$variable = 1;

$loader = new Loader();
$loader->load('file.php');

echo  "\n" . $variable;

echo "\n" .  method();
```

$cat file.php

```
<?php
function method() {
    echo "hi i am a method";
}
```

outputs

```
$php foo.php 
hello i am a variablehi i am a method
```

but seriously, don't do this. You seem to be trying to use includes() as a vector of code reuse, when it is mostly envisioned as a method for code separation.  You are messing with phps' natural scoping in a hard to debug and unpredictable way.  This is an anti-pattern.